# Creating an Apply Now Page and keep getting this error when trying to submit sample applications on React JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, vite

I have a problem with website project. I am trying to create an apply now page so that people can apply on my website. I am trying to connect the front end to the back end and keep getting this error message: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`
My project consists of a folder structure like this:

```
- tbs-website
 - client
  - node_modules
  - public
  - src
   - css
    - apply.css
    - FileInput.css
    - home.css
   - js
    - FileInput.jsx
    - submitApplication.jsx
   - pages
    - applynow.jsx
    - home.jsx
    - index.jsx
    - trafficcontrol.jsx
   - App.jsx
   - main.jsx
  - package.json
  - package-lock.json
  - vite.config.js 
 - server
  - node_modules 
  - src
   - server.js
  - package.json
  - package-lock.json
```

My Apply Now page (**applynow.jsx**)

```
// applynow.jsx
import React from 'react';
import '../css/apply.css'
import FileInput from '../js/FileInput';
import { sendFormDataToServer } from '../js/submitApplication'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
const Apply = () => {

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Collect form data
    const formData = {
      email1: 'tbsolutions9@gmail.com',
      email2: 'tbsolutions3@gmail.com',
      email3: 'tbsolutions4@gmail.com'
    };

    // Send form data to server
    const result = await sendFormDataToServer(formData);
    console.log(result); // Log the result
  };
    return (
      <html>
        <head>
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></meta>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="/index.css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
          
            <header class="header">
      <a href="#">
        <img class="logo" alt="TBS logo" src="tbs logo.png" />
      </a>

      <nav class="main-nav">
        <Link to="/applynow">Apply Now</Link>
        <ul class="main-nav-list">
          <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="http://www.msn.com">Traffic Control</a></li>
          <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#how">Clothing and Bags</a></li>
          <li>
            <a class="main-nav-link" href="#how">Banners and Posters</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#how">Business Cards</a></li>
          <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#how">Window Vinyls</a></li>
          <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#meals">Items</a></li>
          <li>
            <a class="main-nav-link" href="#testimonials">Signs</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
          <li>
            <a class="main-nav-link nav-cta" href="#cta">Get a free quote</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <button class="btn-mobile-nav">
        <ion-icon class="icon-mobile-nav" name="menu-outline"></ion-icon>
        <ion-icon class="icon-mobile-nav" name="close-outline"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </header>
        
        <main>
        <div class="apply-container">
          <h1 class="apply-now">APPLY NOW</h1>
          <h2 class="descript">Discover a career with TBS, 
          a premier leader in traffic control solutions! 
          As a dynamic and rapidly growing company in the traffic management industry, 
          TBS takes pride in revolutionizing how we navigate and manage traffic flow. 
          Join our dedicated team and contribute to creating safer, 
          more efficient roadways.</h2>
        </div>
        <form class="apply-set -- box" id="applicationForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div class="container container--narrow page-section">

          <h1 class="job-app-box">Job Application Form</h1>
          <h2 class="job-fill">Please Fill Out the Form Below to Submit Your Job Application!</h2>
            
            
          <label class="name">Name: </label>
        <div class="first-input">
        
          <div class="first-name">
              <div class="name-input">
                <label class="first-label-name">First Name *</label>
                  <input class="first-name-input"text="first-name--input" placeholder="Enter First Name"></input>
              </div>
              </div>
            <div class="last-name">
              <div class="name-input"> 
            <label class="last-label-name">Last Name *</label>
              <input class="last-name-input"text="last-name--input" placeholder="Enter Last Name"></input>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <label class="emailphone-label">Email/Phone Number:</label>
            
            <div class="emailphone-input">
            
            <div class="email">
            <div class="name-input">
            <label class="email-name">Email *</label>
              <input class="email-box"text="email--input" placeholder="Enter Email"></input>
              </div> 
              </div>
              
            <div class="phone">
            <div class="name-input">
            <label class="phone">Phone Number *</label>
              <input class="phone-box"text="phone--input" placeholder="Enter Phone Number"></input>
              </div>
              </div>  
              </div>  

            <label class="resume-label">Resume/Cover Letter:</label>
              <h1 class="resume-note">Note: You can only submit .doc, .pdf, .txt, and .pages files</h1>
            <div class="resume-input">
              <div class="resume">
              <div class="name-input">
                <label class="resume-name">Resume *</label>
                <FileInput></FileInput>
                </div>
                </div>   

                <div class="cover-letter">
              <div class="name-input">
                <label class="cover-name">Cover Letter</label>
                <FileInput></FileInput>
                </div>
                </div>    
            </div>
            <label class="message-label">Message: </label>
            <h1 class="message-note">Tell us why you want to work for TBS! </h1>
   
                <textarea class="message-text"
                          name="message"

                          placeholder="Enter Message"></textarea>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn--full submit-app">
            Submit Application
          </button>

          </div>



         </form>
         <footer class="footer">
                  <div class="site-footer__inner container container--narrow">

                        <h1 class="tbs-copy">
                          <a href="index.html">&copy; 2023 Traffic & Barrier Solutions, LLC</a>
                        </h1>
                        <h1 class="footer-number">706-263-0175</h1>
                      </div>

            </footer>
        </main>
        </body>
        </html>
    )

    }
export default Apply;
```

All of my css has been successfully exported from apply.css to the back-end and that was part of the problem. However, my next problem is that I am getting the error when I submit a dummy application to my gmails. I have two JavaScript files that connect to the applynow.jsx. However, I don't know if I need to include the App.jsx and the main.jsx files in the client folder. Here is my submitApplication.jsx file:

```
// submitApplication.jsx
export async function sendFormDataToServer(formData) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5173/submit-gmail-addresses', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(formData),
        });

        if (response.ok) {
            // Handle success
            return 'Success: Form data submitted to server';
        } else {
            // Handle failure
            return 'Error: Failed to submit form data to server';
        }
    } catch (error) {
        // Handle network error
        console.error('Network error:', error);
        return 'Error: Network error';
    }
}
```

And here is the server.js from the server/src folder:

```
// server.js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const path = require('path')
const app = express();
const port = 5173;

// Middleware to parse JSON bodies
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Endpoint to handle form submission

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));

app.post('/submit-gmail-addresses', async (req, res) => {
    const formData = req.body;

    // Process the form data
    console.log('Received form data:', formData);

    try {
        // Send application to specified Gmail addresses
        const result = await sendApplication(formData);

        // Send success response
        res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'Application sent successfully' });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error sending application:', error);
        // Send error response
        res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: 'Failed to send application' });
    }
});

app.get('/', (res) => {
    // Send response for '/applynow' route
    res.sendFile(path.resolve)
    res.send('This is the home page');
});
// Endpoint to handle requests to '/applynow'
app.get('/applynow', (res) => {
    // Send response for '/applynow' route
    res.sendFile(path.resolve)
    res.send('This is the apply now page');
});

// Function to send application
async function sendApplication(formData) {
    // Configure Nodemailer transporter
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        // Configure transporter options (e.g., SMTP settings)
    });

    // Construct email message
    const mailOptions = {
        from: 'your@example.com', // Sender's email address
        to: [formData.email1, formData.email2, formData.email3], // Array of recipient email addresses
        subject: 'New Job Application',
        text: `\nName: ${formData.firstName} ${formData.lastName}\nEmail: ${formData.email}\nPhone: ${formData.phone}\nResume: ${formData.resumeFile}\nCover Letter: ${formData.coverLetterFile}\nMessage: ${formData.message}`,
    };

    // Send email
    await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
}

// Start the server
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

So I want it to send all job applications to all three of these Gmails but unfortunately, it displays the error message in the "Inspect". Whenever I try to start my application up on the terminal through `C:\Users\rowel\OneDrive\Desktop\TBSweb\tbs-website\server\src> node server.js`, it displays **Server is listening at http://localhost:5173**, however, when I submit everything on the apply now page, it won't work. If I need to explain more about my lines of code here or add more files of code, feel free ask more questions so I can add more code to this forum. Otherwise, I need help to get my VITE/REACT to submit applications from the client's end to the server's end, then server's end sends emails of the submitted application to the emails listed.

Comment: Why the [tag:java] tag?

Comment: Sorry! I didn't realize i tagged Java in this forum

Comment: Are you seeing the console log in your handler? Also, does your handler have scope of your ‘sendApplication’ function, given it is defined after your handler?

Answer (score -2):

1. Check URL paths and API endpoint correctness in your React app.
2. Ensure the server is configured correctly to handle API requests.
3. Verify CORS settings if your React app and server are on different domains.
4. Inspect the browser console and network tab for detailed error messages.
5. Restart both React and backend servers, and ensure backend services are running.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).